# Pull all occurrences of the induction variable into the conclusion in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I find the book "Isabelle/HOL: A Proof Assitant for Higher-Order logic" a very good reference to improve the apply-style coding in Isabelle. In several parts of the books (for instance section 9.2) the authors state that a good heuristic for induction is to:

> pull all occurrence of the induction variable into the conclusion
>   using ⟶

but the way they do this is by restating the goal as a lemma with the ⟶ instead of  ⟹. I want to do this automatically in apply-style. My current goal is of the form:

```
⋀ param. A ⟹ B
```

How would you pull A into the conclusions using apply-style?

Comment: @xanonec, i mixed question that comment was intended for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53486780/convert-an-isar-proof-of-forall-statement-to-apply-style

Comment: @xanonec the command you indicated works perfect for me, feel free to add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native solution is to use the method `atomize`, e.g. `apply(atomize (full))` (section 9.5 in the reference manual). Also, you can use `apply(erule rev_mp)`.